# FullCalendar - Extra bottom space on each row

Tags: html, css, fullcalendar

I'm trying to add extra space at the bottom of each row when using a `resourceTimeline` so the user have space to easily select and create a new event, something like this:
[image: screenshot of what I'm describing with randomly generated data]
*(Randomly generated data)*

I tried doing it with CSS but, as you can see in the screenshot, it messes up the resources.

```css
.fc-timeline-lane-frame{
    height: 70px !important;
}
```

Comment: Presumably you'd need to do the same to the resource list

Comment: Using padding was the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding padding to `.fc-resource` did the job for me:

```css
#calendar .fc-resource{
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

For some reason it also makes the events narrower, which is desired in my case.

[image: desired result]